# How to load the js and css files from other than root when creating a build?

Tags: reactjs

I created a build of my creat-react-app reactjs application.  It is very simple for now.

So I am loading this react app from within a web application, but it is loading not from the root but from a subdomain.

The problem is the css and js files are expected to be at the root ie.

```
/static/js/main.3a52edf1.chunk.js
```

How can I change this to:

```
 /public/app/static/js/main.3a52edf1.chunk.js
```

I am currently justing doing `yarn run build` to generate my build.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can you the `homepage` attribute in `pacakge.json`

References:

https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/xtgpx9kssz-set-the-relative-path-of-assets-in-a-cra-app
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json set the homepage attribute to:

```
"homepage": "."
```

Now, all your imports will be relative to your index.html